# Error while binding form request play-framework 2.5.4

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-2.3, ebean

I am using play-framework-java 2.5.4.

**I want to bind a user-input-from values to my model class variables.**

This is my controller function that except form **POST** :

```
public Result formSubmit()
    {
        MlmModel mlmModel;
        play.data.Form<MlmModel> form = play.data.Form.form(MlmModel.class).bindFromRequest();
        mlmModel = form.get();
        mlmModel.save();
        mlmModel.callUpdate();
        return ok(Json.toJson(mlmModel));
    }
```

But I am **getting this error**

```
[CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error(s) binding form: {"parent_id":["Invalid value"]}]
```

**because, one of my input field is not compulsory to fill by user.**

It's fine if user left blank some fields.

But my code should

- save all data that user provides to database and
- should save **0** by default for the fields    left blank by user .

I am Using **play-Eben** and my database server is MySQL 5.x

How can I achieve this?

Edit 1 :

MlmModel.java

```
@Entity
public class MlmModel extends Model
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    public Long ID;
    public Logic logic;
    public MlmModel() {
        this.parent_id = 0;
        logic = new Logic(this);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String name;


    public long getParent_id() {
        return parent_id;
    }

    public void setParent_id(long parent_id) {
        if (String.valueOf(parent_id).isEmpty())
            this.parent_id = 0;
        this.parent_id = parent_id;
    }
    @Column(columnDefinition = "long default 0")
    public long parent_id;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date created_time = new Date();

    public Long balance = new Long(0);

    public static Finder<Long, MlmModel> find = new Finder<Long,MlmModel>(MlmModel.class);



    public List<ValidationError> validate()
    {
        List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
        if (Long.toString(parent_id).isEmpty())
            parent_id = 0;
        if (errors.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else
            return errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for `MlmModel`.

Comment: @mkurz I have added Model class, please have a look.

Comment: Are you sure you do not submit a value for `parent_id`? It looks like the browser submits some value which is not of type `long` which then Play tries to parse into the Form which of course fails.

Comment: Offtopic: The line `if (String.valueOf(parent_id).isEmpty())` makes no sense because `parent_id` is of type long which can not be `null` - it **always** has a value (`0` by default). So if you look at the string representation it will **never** be empty. You should use `public void setParent_id(Long parent_id) {` and then check for `if(parent_id == null)`